# Getting the absolute parent window - browser safe

Tags: jquery, cross-browser

I am working on a C#/JavaScript powered system that previously only worked in Internet Explorer. My job is to make it browser agnostic. It uses a popup engine that I am struggling with.

The code is as follows:

```
function GetBaseIndexDocument() {
    var doc = window;
    var i = 0;
    while (doc.document.getElementById("22411178-0AB6-42AF-8209-FC753F8B58E2") == null && i < 5) {
        i++;
        doc = doc.parent;
    }
    return doc;
}

var _doc = GetBaseIndexDocument(window).document;
var jQ = _doc.parentWindow.$;
```

In Chrome am getting the following error on the final line of code:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '$' of undefined

And this one in FireFox:

> Error: TypeError: _doc.parentWindow is undefined

I am guessing that c the "parentWindow" property does not exist in either of these (and probably several other) browsers. I am unsure of what to replace it with.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Your assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found online that "defaultView" can be used instead of "parentWindow" in all browsers except IE 8 and lower.